# Should I switch my laptop's wifi card?

Tags: wireless, hp, realtek

I've been having wifi problems since installing the latest ubuntu software. After some digging, I found out that my HP Stream 11-r010nr with the Realtek RTL872BE is notoriously bad. I ended up purchasing an external antenna, but this is taking one of my two USB connections.
It looks like the original card can be replaced by the Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11 ac 1x1 Wi-Fi + Bluetooth 4.2 Combo Adapter (MU-MIMO supported) HP part # L17365-005.
I'm not sure I want to do this if the RTL8821CE is also prone to problems.
Any comments?

Comment: Did you try the rtl8823be ant_sel parameter

Comment: Is that to change the channel? If so, then I tried it. I finally ended up turning it off (or trying, because sometimes it comes back on) and replacing it by an external antenna.

Comment: The rtl8723be used in many HP laptops are known to only have one antenna rather than 2 and the ant_sel parameter is used to force the driver to use the right one as the driver is made for a card with 2 antennas

Comment: I think I'm gonna need more help. When I run "udo modprobe -v rtl8723 ant_sel=1", I get: "modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-45-generic
". I'll try to find this module and see what happens...

Comment: It is rtl8723be not rtl8723

Comment: Hi Jeremy31, you were right. I tried it again and it is working for now. Some hiccups now and then, but most of the time a strong signal. I will keep an eye on it for a few days and if there are no more problems I can close the thread.